# Createblobstream Read and Write a Record type to Blobfield using FDTable / Sqlite

Tags: sqlite, delphi

I am trying to store a Record type into a blobfield. I am using SQLite and FDTable. I cannot get this to work. I have reviewed all of the other posts regarding Createblobstream and have tried numerous approaches with no success.
My record is much larger so I simplified to this as I get the same result.

I cannot access the data when I read it back, always inaccessible. I have used this code before with Delphi 2010, but I was using an access database.

Any direction would be greatly appreciated.

```
TTestRec = Record
  Name : String;
  Number : Integer;
end;

procedure TForm.WriteBlobClick(Sender : TObject);
var
  R : TTestRec;
  BS : TStream;
  BFld : TBlobField;
begin
  R.Name:=Edit4.Text;
  R.Number:=Strtoint(Edit5.Text);

  BFld:=TBlobfield(Table1Settings);

  if Table1.State<>dsEdit then
    Table1.Edit;

  BS:= Table1.CreateBlobStream(BFld,bmWrite);
  Try
    BS.Writebuffer(R,Sizeof(TTestRec));
  Finally
    BS.Free;
  End;

  dmdata.Table1.Post;
end;

procedure TForm1.ReadBlobClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  R : TTestRec;
  BS : TStream;
  BFld : TBlobField;
begin
  BFld:=TBlobfield(Table1Settings);
  BS:= Table1.CreateBlobStream(BFld,bmRead);
  Try
    BS.ReadBuffer(R,sizeof(TTestRec));
  Finally
    BS.Free;
  End;

  Edit4.Text:=R.Name;
  Edit5.Text:=inttostr(R.Number);
end;
```

Thanks
-Tyson

Comment: Cannot have worked previously either, unless strings were mapped to short strings {$H-}.  String variables do not carry the character payload, they are only pointers. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3820996/delphi-2010-how-to-save-a-whole-record-to-a-file) question for instance.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz  Your right! I had previously defined the string length, Name : String[20], but removed that because it doesn't work with android as the compiler. Thanks for the quick response, jogged my memory pretty quick. Ill check out that post and see if I can come up with a different approach.

Comment: LOL, removing what not works generally does not make it work! Read the link I posted, search for string serialization etc..

Comment: Lol, Well, by removing I meant I have many record types defined but only one of them was written to a table, all of the others work as they did before, but now that I am dealing with saving this record to the table, I realized it wasn't working and needed to find a solution. Ultimately I ended up using the KBLib as it seems to be working for what I need. The link I found in the post you provided doesn't work, but I found it here : [kblib]https://github.com/krystianbigaj/kblib)